cursor() raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.") OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available in python telegram bot
I am writing a Telegram bot with Python language and pyrogram library.
My robot is connected to mysql database and I use it as follows at the beginning of the program:
app = Client("my_bot", api_id=config.API_ID, api_hash=config.API_HASH,
             bot_token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=enums.ParseMode.DEFAULT)
with app:
    try:
        database = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user=config.DATABASE_USERNAME,
                                           password=config.DATABASE_PASSWORD, database=config.DATABASE_NAME)
    except Exception as er:
        print(f'SQL Error: {er}')
        exit()

I also use the following decorator for robot handling:
@app.on_message(filters.private & filters.text & filters.user(config.ADMINS_ID))
async def handlerTextAdmin(clientP: Client, message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    msg_id = message.id
    if text == 'Users':
        connection = database.cursor(buffered=True)
        connection.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users')
        result = connection.fetchone()
        if not result:
            result = [0]
        connection.close()
        text = f'Users: {result[0]}'
        await message.reply(text, reply_to_message_id=msg_id)
        return

When I run the robot, it runs well and there are no problems
But when I run it with the following command, I have a problem:
nohup python main.py &

After several hours of execution, I get the following error:
File "/home/scraperb/virtualenv/MoviesBot/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 772, in cursor
    raise OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.

What is the problem?
Is it possible that the main connection will be automatically closed after a few hours?
What should I do to solve this problem?

It's really confusing that you use the variable name connection for the cursor. When I saw connection.close() I thought you were closing the whole database connection.

That query will always return a row, there's no need to check if not result:.
